# How can I create a function that navigates through an array?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, arrays

So I have an array:

```
var summaryList;
summaryList = ['a','b','c', 'd']
```

Each item in the array represents an element I want to grab focus. I want to do this by using left/right arrow keypresses that navigate through each item in the array. After focus is called, I want to set the border to yellow to show that it's the active:

```
$(document).keydown(function(e){
        if (e.keyCode == 37) {
            console.log('left')        
        }
        if (e.keyCode == 39) {
            var pos;
            pos = this.summaryList[];

            console.log('right');
            console.log(pos);
            $(pos[0 +1]).focus().css('border', "yellow");
        } 
});
```

My problem is that the console.log(pos) comes back as undefined when I want it to read the current item in the summaryList array. After each key press, the array item should move over by one index position

Comment: post your html please

Comment: Okay, but so far you've not described a *problem*. Stackoverflow is here for you when you get stuck with the actual writing of your code because you've run into a situation where you think your code should do something, but instead it does something else, and after investigating it yourself, you still can't figure out why that would be. SO is not here to help you write your code as you're working on it.

Comment: You can do the colour change in your style sheet by using the `:focus` selector.

Comment: Sorry for not clarifying-- I indeed am having trouble selecting the current array. I am getting a console log of (undefined) when I want a log that reads the current index item in the array (pos)

Comment: One approach would be to have a `currentItem` variable declared outside your function. Then your if statements could add or subtract 1 from that variable depending on the keypress (don't forget to allow for it going past the first and last array indices). Then use that variable as an index to the array to set focus.

Comment: that makes sense, I'll try that now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var summaryList = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'];

// Hold reference to the currently focussed position
var currentPosition = 0;

// Maximum position we can navigate to is the last item in the summary list
var maxFocusablePosition = summaryList.length - 1;

// Utility function to focus a given position value
function focusPosition(position) {
    $(summaryList[position]).focus().css('border', 'yellow');
}

// Focus the first one by default
focusPosition(currentPosition);

$(document).keydown(function (event) {
    if (event.keyCode === 37) {
        currentPosition > 0 ? currentPosition-- : 0;
    }

    if (event.keyCode === 39) {
        currentPosition < maxFocusablePosition ? currentPosition++ : maxFocusablePosition;
    }

    focusPosition(currentPosition);
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your contribution, I see your mindset writing this logic, it's not picking up the keypresses however

Comment: The keydown handler is not being invoked?

Comment: The keydown handler is being invoked, I attached 2 console.log statements to test for that. The strings from the log are displayed but the function does not. There are no errors either

Comment: Where exactly is the issue? is focusPosition() triggered? Is the selector created for jQuery valid?

Comment: the focusPosition function is being called. I think the problem is with the jQuery selector, it's not performing any action

Comment: what does your summaryList array look like?

Comment: if you'd like i can do a screenshare with you

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/105850/discussion-between-prashant-palikhe-and-kunal-ojha).

Comment: Would you know how to add a combo keypress--say for example ctrl + left/right arrow?

Answer (score 0):

`pos = this.summaryList;`

should just be

`pos = summaryList;`

`this` refers to the document. The summaryList is defined on the window.

Alternatively you could do `window.summaryList`, but it's rarely necessary to add "window." when calling items from the global scope.

---

The other problem you have is..

`$(pos[0 +1]).focus().css('border', "yellow");`

`pos[0 +1]` is going to be an item from your array, for example, "c".

`$('c')` is not a valid selector, so that is going to just confuse jQuery.

Comment: the array represents hard coded element IDs, there isn't an issue with the selector

Comment: @KunalOjha `$('c')` is not a valid selector. period. you select elements by id like this.. `$('#c')`